# Crystal Report add leading zeros but do not show for sorting calculated field in group

Tags: crystal-reports, hide, leading-zero

I have a calculated field in Crystal Report which starts with numbers and is already sorted as text. I want to sort it like numbers. The calculated field consists of two numberfields and a textfield. Like this:

```
{numberfield1} & "." & {numberfield2} & " " & {textfield}
```

The Report shows the data like this (already sorted):

```
1.2 sometext  
10.3 sometext  
2.30 sometext  
2.4 sometext
```

What I want to achive is to sort first for {numberfield1} and then {numberfield2} with following result:

```
1.2 sometext  
2.4 sometext  
2.30 sometext  
10.3 sometext
```

I already tried this:
http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=19668
so my code looks like this:

```
totext({numberfield1},"00", 0) & "." &  
totext({numberfield2},"00",0) & " " &  
{textfield}
```

As far as I understand, this code should hide the leading zeros. But it does not. The leading zeros are still displayed in the report. At least, the sorting is working. The result:

```
01.02 sometext  
02.04 sometext  
02.30 sometext  
10.30 sometext
```

I also tried:
    cstr(val({numberfield}))
    totext(tonumber({numberfield}))
These remove the leading zeros, but the sorting does not work.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You need two formulas. The first - with the leading zeros - will be used for sorting. The second - without the leading zeros - will be used to display the values.

Comment: Thank you so far. Can you provide a little more detail or give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a first formula. Let's call it "TheOneThatYouSee":

```
{numberfield1} & "." & {numberfield2} & " " & {textfield}
//i just copied your formula
```

Create a second formula. Let's call it "TheOneThatYouDoNotSee":

```
totext({numberfield1},"00", 0) & "." &  
totext({numberfield2},"00",0) & " " &  
{textfield}
//i just copied your formula
```

Then you sort by TheOneThatYouDoNotSee (group by).

Then you put the TheOneThatYouSee in the details section.